# Very strange WFE behaviour

Tags: 2010

firstly thanks for helping!

One of my WFE servers seems to have a period of around 20 minutes where it appears to either run out of resource or appears to be disconnected from the network. Application log errors are created by the hundred. I checked the IIS logs, and it is still receiving/ processing GET requests, so my guess it that the network is fine, but interestingly in the ULS logs I get a bunch of these errors:

```
System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: An operation on a socket could not be performed because the system lacked sufficient buffer space or because a queue was full 127.0.0.1:32843   
 at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.DoConnect(EndPoint endPointSnapshot, SocketAddress socketAddress)    
 at System.Net.ServicePoint.ConnectSocketInternal(Boolean connectFailure, Socket s4, Socket s6, Socket& socket, IPAddress& address, ConnectSocketState state, IAsyncResult asyncResult, Int32 timeout, Exception& exception)
```

So, I am wondering if anybody else has experienced this type of error, and if so, what would you recommend in terms of moving forward with troubleshooting?

Many thanks
Steve

Comment: Please give us more details, such as how many WFEs in total you have, how much memory you have on these WFEs, the average occupancy of the memory on these servers, how many web applications you have concurrently running, and how many users roughly access the site. Also do you often reboot this machine, and does this issue recur at the same time every day, etc.

Comment: Hello James, Thanks for offering to help.  We actually resolved the issue in the end. It eventually turned out to be a problem with a physical host being faulty. The reason we found it hard to isolate was due to the fact that vSphere would migrate machines from host to host, and essentially pass the problem onto whichever server had been migrated onto the faulty physical host.

Answer (score 1):

We actually resolved the issue in the end. It eventually turned out to be a problem with a physical host being faulty. The reason we found it hard to isolate was due to the fact that vSphere would migrate machines from host to host, and essentially pass the problem onto whichever server had been migrated onto the faulty physical host.

Answer (score 0):

Are you running out of run out of resources (sockets?) or memory. Try testing the following command at prompt run: `netstat -ab`
Some addtional information regarding this case: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/196271

Comment: Hello Falak, Yes, I think this is the issue.  To try and capture this at the time it happens I have created a scheduled task to capture the socket data..  Thank you for your help, I will keep this thread updated with more information as I find it. :)